# Discard Values repeated in particular date time intervals

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I'm working on a de-duplicating a dataframe based on a 14 day interval of repetition, meaning 
if value in column b is repeated within a 14 day period then I need to discard the duplicate and if isn't they keep all the values

This is what the data frame looks like:

```
date    event
2016-01-17  aa
2016-01-18  bb
2016-01-19  cc
2016-01-20  dd
2016-01-17  ee
2016-01-18  ff
2016-01-19  aa
2016-01-20  bb
2016-10-21  cc
2016-10-22  dd
2016-10-23  ee
```

Here the events aa and bb are repeated within a 14 day period so the two duplicate values need to be taken off

Desired result:

```
date    event
2016-01-17  aa
2016-01-18  bb
2016-01-19  cc
2016-01-20  dd
2016-01-17  ee
2016-01-18  ff
2016-10-21  cc
2016-10-22  dd
2016-10-23  ee
```

I could use:

```
df<- df[order(df[,'date'],-df[,'event']),]
df = df[!duplicated(df$date),]
```

but this would only take off specific events repeated on same day and not in the 14 day interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data table
setDT(df)

## create groups based on 14 days interval
df$group <- cumsum(ifelse(difftime(df$date,
                                      shift(df$date, fill = df$date[1]), 
                                      units = "days") >= 14 ,1, 0)) + 1
# get unique values
df = df[,unique(.SD, by='event'), group][,.(date, event)]

print(df)
         date event
1: 2016-01-17    aa
2: 2016-01-18    bb
3: 2016-01-19    cc
4: 2016-01-20    dd
5: 2016-01-17    ee
6: 2016-01-18    ff
7: 2016-10-21    cc
8: 2016-10-22    dd
9: 2016-10-23    ee
```